# Iteration and value change in vector

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a program to convert grades into a grading scale.

```
from bisect import bisect
def grade(score, breakpoints=[-1.4, 1, 3, 5.6, 8.6, 9.6], grades='m''0''2''4''7''t''T'):
    i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
    for i in grade: 
        if i == 'm':
            grade[i] = -3
        if i == '0':
            grade[i] = 00
        elif i == 't':
            grade[i] = 10
        elif i == 'T':
            grade[i] = 12
    return grades[i]
[grade(score) for score in [-2, 3.4, 5.5, 1.2, 11.8, 8.1, 7.3]]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
 for i in grade:

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I have tried to change it directly when I attribute the grades in line 2, but it won't let me enter values that have more than one character (i.e -3, 00, 10 or 12), which is why I'm trying to change the value after the grades have been converted.

Thanks.

Comment: `grade` is the name of your function, what *did* you expect from `for i in grade:`? Are you trying to test `grades[i]`, in which case: why the loop?

Comment: switch the name of the function suppose to solve it up.
i am not sure what you trying the achieve, 
i think you need instead of return you meant for yield.

Comment: I want to go over each of the newly attributed scores (grades='m''0''2''4''7''t''T') and for the ones that I have put in the loop, I would like to replace them with the corresponding number.

Comment: there is literally the same example in the [`bisect documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html). Use that as a guideline

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's what I've used for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not fully understanding what you trying to achieve i have some comments for you that will work good for you. first able use HANDLERS it will be much better for your writing. second what are you calling is it a function, list ?? 
look at this example it is not finished but what are you trying to do:

```
from bisect import bisect

GRADE_HANDLER = {'T': 12, 't': 10, '0': 00, 'm': -3}

def grade(score, breakpoints=[-1.4, 1, 3, 5.6, 8.6, 9.6], grades='m''0''2''4''7''t''T'):
    # WHy you use it??? and where?
    bisect_value = bisect(breakpoint,score)
    # grade is not a list
    for i in grades:
        grades[i] = GRADE_HANDLER[i]

    # what are you returning ??


[grade(score) for score in [-2, 3.4, 5.5, 1.2, 11.8, 8.1, 7.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo. 
There should be "grades", not "grade"